# any body ever fully diagonalized a 200,000*200,000 symmetric matrix?

Tags: mpi, parallel-processing

it is possible to diagonalize it with matlab on the cluster of my university

but i want to do it with fortran and using some parallel algorithm

i know "scalapack" can do it (but i do not know how to use it yet)

anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: The obvious suggestion is: do it with SCALAPACK.  Which makes me wonder what your real question is.  I can't say that I have ever diagonalised a matrix of those dimensions, I'd be surprised to learn that it had never been done.

Comment: Is the matrix dense?  What problem did it come from?  What are you trying to do with it?  (Why do you need all the eigenvectors?)  You can almost certainly do what you want without computing the full decomposition.

Comment: surely we need to fully diagonalize it! since we need to fully diagonalize it, it does not make any difference whether the matrix is sparse or dense. it is sparse actually.

Comment: and it has been done! actually it can be done with matlab on a 64bit computer with more than 10 GB memory. but i want to do it with scalapack which may be a bit faster

Answer (score 0):

If you have [Parallel Computing Toolbox](http://www.mathworks.com/products/parallel-computing/) and [MATLAB Distributed Computing Server](http://www.mathworks.com/products/distriben/index.html), you can call MATLAB's [backslash](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/mldivide.html) operator on really large [distributed arrays](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bquvksw.html).

I have never tried with an array that large, but it might be possible. Note that the distributed arrays use ScaLAPACK to perform things like backslash.

EDIT: You'd need about 320Gb of memory across the cluster machines just to store one copy of the array. You're probably going to need at least 4 times that amount of memory to operate on the array. Maybe more, depending on the operations you wish to perform.